# Flutter Runtime error: invalid argument (dartObject ): could not convert: instance of 'LatLng'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation, flutterflow

In a Flutter application using dart, when adding a field to a Firebase Firestore object using this code:

```
     geolocation: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
```

I got the following runtime error:

**invalid argument (dartObject ): could not convert: instance of 'LatLng'**

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the GeoPoint constructor:

```
     geolocation: GeoPoint(latitude, longitude),
```